# Swift BoringSSL

Tags: json, swift, xcode

I'm quite new to Swift and have a problem that I can't solve since about 1,5 weeks.
I was checking every forum if anyone has the same problem, but I couldn't find anyone. Would be cool if someone could help me.
I want to get data from an website through parsing json.

My code to get the data looks like this:

```
func getData(){
    let url = URL(string: "https://api.coinmarketcap.com/v1/ticker/ethereum/?convert=EUR")
    let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url!) { (data, response, error) in
        if error != nil
        {
            print("ERROR")
        } else
        {
            if let content = data
            {
                do
                {
                    //Array
                    let myJson = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: content, options: JSONSerialization.ReadingOptions.mutableContainers) as AnyObject
                    print(myJson)
                }
                catch
                {

                }
            }
        }
    }; task.resume()
}
```

Every time I start the code in the simulator or real Device (it doesn't matter which one) I get the following code in the console:

2017-11-20 14:40:23.813604+0100 JsonTest[17534:5500248] [BoringSSL] Function boringssl_context_get_peer_sct_list: line 1757 received sct extension length is less than sct data length

Thanks for your help.

Comment: XCode nowadays logs a lot of thin, doesn't always matter. The question is what work/doesn't work with your current code? App Transport Security ? Error print? What about printing the errors?

Comment: I am using this code in viewWillAppear, so that the user has latest information when he starts the app or changes between tab bars. And in an extra function when he clicks on a button. I only get the boringSSl error when the data is downloaded the first time. I have got labels where the data that I download should be displayed, but it doesn't display after the first download. I hope you know what i mean? :)